# Perl code stop execution at a point, don't know why

Tags: perl

[image]This is my code. It's called by a ClearCase trigger. It was working fine, but after I reformat the code with Padre Perl Tidy or something like this. If I open the file with Notepad++, looks like some format is wrong. But Padre doesn't show any syntax error, and the file can be run with "perl filename" with no compile error.

```
sub processUnixFile {
    print "# *** start processUnixFile ***\n\n";
    my $result;    
    my (
        $target_servers, $target_permission, $app_name,
        $target_env,     $file,              $fname,
        $ftype,          $target_view,       $app_banner
    ) = @_;

    if ( $app_name eq "UARF" ) {
        print "$app_name NOT AUTOMATED, exit 0\n";
        exit 0;
    }

    print "Retrieve server information from table ${app_name}_ENV.txt\n";
    my %envs;
    %envs = bccpbmod::getUnixEnvVar( $app_name, $target_env );
```

This is the output:

```
# *** start processUnixFile ***
Retrieve server information fr
```

Comment: Well, it looks incomplete. There's no closing brace for the sub.  Did you post all of it?

Comment: No, I didn't post the complete code, it's too long. I just added the screenshot in Notepad++.

Comment: You should post the minimum amount of code, that compiles and reproduces the problem. It's hard to help otherwise.

Comment: @tambre, the file has 2K lines, lots of functions. It compiles with no issue. I've never seen this happen, so just want to in what cases this can happen.

Comment: Like I said, you should post the minimum amount of compilable code, that would reproduce the problem. Ie. we would be able to compile the code, run it and have it reproduce the problem with as little code as possible.

Comment: I agree with [tambre](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974531/perl-code-stop-execution-at-a-point-dont-know-why#comment59603671_35974531). There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown, and it is impossible to help you without knowing the full context. You must reduce the code to something of a manageable size that displays the same behaviour. Is your application threaded? Is it still running when your output terminates in this way? Have you tried adding `STDOUT->flush` after each print statement?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. And why is your image different from the text of the same function?

Comment: @Borodin, I just checked all the actual process is done. So must be related to the output flush. It's ok now after adding $| = 1; at the beginning of file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JirongHu: I'm pleased to have helped. I've posted my comment as an answer, together with a suggestion to use `STDOUT->autoflush` instead of `$| = 1`; it's far more clear what it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `STDOUT->flush` after each print statement?

If that works then you should put

```
STDOUT->autoflush
```

at the top of your code. It's far more expressive than `$| = 1`